# How to detect when a player looks at a pig with name "173"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried this:

```
/execute if entity @e[type=minecraft:player] facing entity @e[type=minecraft:pig,tag=173] feet run say hello
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: How precise does this need to be?

Comment: Making a game for 3 disposable players, eh?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to kill an Entity a Player is looking at?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/394965/how-to-kill-an-entity-a-player-is-looking-at). Unfortunately I already cast and retracted a close vote for a different target so can't cast another close vote.

Answer (score 1):

`facing` is completely separate from `if entity <selector>`, it just changes how the command is run (with a different rotation). Detecting if a player looks at something is very hard and requires something called "raytracing" (one example is [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352510/java-minecraft-1-14-2-how-to-recursively-or-otherwise-determine-if-a-closed/352569#352569)).
It might be possible to somehow check if the player looks at an enderman, but even if they're "invisible", you can still see the eyes, so that's probably not what you want.

I recommend changing something else about your setup so that you don't require to check for looking at a pig.