# Trying to use /execute for a player facing a direction

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to use the /execute command to test for whether or not a player is looking at a certain location. However, I don't know how to use /execute since 1.14 came out, so I can't get it to work. In case it changes anything, what I want players to be looking at is a painting. Could anyone tell me what command to use?

Comment: This is very difficult and requires something called "raytracing" (one example is [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352510/java-minecraft-1-14-2-how-to-recursively-or-otherwise-determine-if-a-closed/352569#352569). It's better to think about what you actually want to do, what's your overall project? Maybe you can work around this and don't need to detect players looking at paintings at all.

Comment: It's specifically one painting, but looking at the wall the painting is one would work too. I want the player to be looking away from a wall that disappears in a map I'm making. But I know that if I make a command block to run a command when the player faces -90 degrees, it would be too specific. What would work best would be a way to check if they are looking anywhere from one direction to another. I just hope this doesn't requires raytracing.

Comment: You mean a view angle would be enough? Then just use a range for that, `-70..-110` or so.

Comment: What command would I use to do this?

Comment: Whatever command you want, it's a target selector argument. I thought you knew about facing angles already, didn't you say that? The "Commands" wiki page documents it.