# How to test if a mob/animal has been fed? 1.14

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to test if a fox has been fed sweet berries to execute a command.

Comment: Hi lya, welcome to Arqade! Have you tried anything to test it yet? Please check [this post on Arqade Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13507/what-to-do-before-asking-a-minecraft-commands-question), and the linked [article on commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614/what-are-the-basics-of-commands-in-minecraft-java-edition).

Answer (score 3):

The simple act of giving a fox a sweet berry cannot be detected. What you **can** do is either:

- detecting a player successfully breeding two foxes, using the [`bred_animals` advancement trigger](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Advancements/List_of_triggers#minecraft:bred_animals) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Advancements/List_of_triggers&oldid=1407723#minecraft:bred_animals)) and a condition for the parent to be a fox (this does not detect giving a lone fox a sweet berry)
- detecting a player using a sweet berry and a fox being nearby, using a scoreboard of type [`used:sweet_berries`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Criteria) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Scoreboard&oldid=1427562#Criteria)) (this also detects eating sweet berries while standing near a fox)
- detecting a player using a sweet berry while looking at a fox, this requires "raycasting", which is pretty complicated and a bit resource intensive, an example can be seen in my other answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352510/java-minecraft-1-14-2-how-to-recursively-or-otherwise-determine-if-a-closed/352569#352569) (this also detects a player turning towards a fox while eating a sweet berry)